# Using Python helper function exclude numbers from a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given 3 int values, a b c, return their sum. However, if any of the values is a teen -- in the range 13-19 inclusive -- then that value counts as 0, except 15 and 16 do not count as a teens. Write a separate helper "def fix_teen(n):"that takes in an int value and returns that value fixed for the teen rule. In this way, you avoid repeating the teen code 3 times (i.e. "decomposition").

> Define the helper below and at the same indent level as the main no_teen_sum().Again, you will have two functions for this problem!

```
def no_teen_sum(a, b, c):
  # CODE GOES HERE
def fix_teen(n):
  # CODE GOES HERE
```

Examples:

```
*no_teen_sum(1, 2, 3) → 6 
*no_teen_sum(2, 13, 1) → 3 
*no_teen_sum(2, 1, 14) → 3 
*no_teen_sum(2, 16, 1) → 19
```

I got the 1st part

```
def no_teen_sum(a, b, c):
    total = 0
    for i in (a, b, c):
        if i in range(13, 20):
            x = 0
        else:
            x = 1
        total += i*x
    return total
```

just struggling on the second

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However, if any of the values is a teen -- in the range 13-19 inclusive -- then that value counts as 0, ***except 15 and 16 do not count as a teens.***

You forgot about `15` & `16` in your current solution (and you didn't use the second function inside of it).

```
>>> def no_teen_sum(a, b, c):  # your solution
...     total = 0
...     for i in (a, b, c):
...         if i in range(13, 20):
...             x = 0
...         else:
...             x = 1
...         total += i*x
...     return total
... 
>>> no_teen_sum(1, 2, 3) == 6
True
>>> no_teen_sum(2, 13, 1) == 3
True
>>> no_teen_sum(2, 1, 14) == 3
True
>>> no_teen_sum(2, 16, 1) == 19  # 16 doesn't count as 0
False

# Solution
>>> def no_teen_sum(a, b, c):
...     return sum(fix_teen(num) for num in (a, b, c))
... 
... 
... def fix_teen(n):
...     teens = {13, 14, 17, 18, 19}
...     return 0 if n in teens else n
... 
>>> no_teen_sum(1, 2, 3) == 6
True
>>> no_teen_sum(2, 13, 1) == 3
True
>>> no_teen_sum(2, 1, 14) == 3
True
>>> no_teen_sum(2, 16, 1) == 19
True
```

Simplified version:

```
def no_teen_sum(a, b, c):
    result = 0
    for num in (a, b, c):
        result += fix_teen(num)
    return result


def fix_teen(n):
    if n in {13, 14, 17, 18, 19}:
        return 0
    else:
        return n


if __name__ == '__main__':
    assert no_teen_sum(1, 2, 3) == 6
    assert no_teen_sum(2, 13, 1) == 3
    assert no_teen_sum(2, 1, 14) == 3
    assert no_teen_sum(2, 16, 1) == 19
```

Comment: return 0 if n in new_teen else n. This sentence so simple and yet so complicated.

Comment: I love the way you use if and for after the return, I never thought that was possible

Comment: @SamirTendulkar It's a ternary operator. I'll update my answer in just a few seconds with a simplified example of both.

Answer (score 0):

Created a function to handle the teen rule and passed the listed arguments through and then summed them up. I'm new to coding, hope this helps.

```
    def fix_teen(n):
       teens = list(range(13,20))
       if n == 15 or n == 16:
           return n
       elif n in teens:
           return 0
       else:
           return n

    def no_teen_sum(a, b, c):
       helper1 = fix_teen(a)
       helper2 = fix_teen(b)
       helper3 = fix_teen(c)
       return(helper1 + helper2 + helper3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to write as per the problem statement, here is my submission. Please do review.

```
def no_teen_sum(a, b, c):
  def fix_teen(x):
    if (x == 15) or (x == 16):
      return x
    elif x in range(13, 20):
      return 0
    else:
      return x
      
  sum = fix_teen(a) + fix_teen(b) + fix_teen(c)
  return sum
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def no_teen_sum(a, b, c):

    teen = [13, 14, 17, 18, 19]
    if a in teen and b in teen and c in teen:
        return 0
    elif a in teen and b in teen and c not in teen:
        return c
    elif a in teen and c in teen and b not in teen:
        return b
    elif b in teen and c in teen and a not in teen: 
        return a
    elif a in teen and b not in teen and c not in teen:
        return b + c
    elif c in teen and a not in teen and b not in teen:
        return a + b
    elif b in teen and a not in teen and c not in teen: 
        return a + c
    return a + b + c
```

Comment: Your answer would be improved by some explanation, so people will understand why it is better than the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
def no_teen_sum(a,b,c):
    return fix_teen(a) + fix_teen(b) +fix_teen(c)
def fix_teen(n):
    teen = {13,14,17,18,19}
    if n in teen:
```

I have tried to make it as simple as I can